# SVN: how to check if a changeset was already merged but the mergeinfo are missing on the superfolder?

Tags: svn, merge, version-control

Let's assume to have 2 `branches` each of which contains the folder (let's call it `a`):

```
c:\svn\trunk -- 1st branch
c:\svn\main  -- 2nd branch
```

If I merge a changeset from the subfolder (`http://repository:81\svn\trunk\a` to `c:\svn\main\a`) the mergeinfo on the root (`c:\svn\main`) are **not** updated.

The next developer who tries to merge from `c:\svn\trunk` to `c:\svn\main` SVN cannot use the **merge tracking** feature from SVN since che updated mergeinfo are only for the subfolders.

When I merge a changeset if the files from the changeset are all contained in the subfolder I'm merging from, I want to propagate the mergeinfo to the parent folder. Is it possible?

Comment: Just need some clarification on a few things. Your first line you state you have ..\svn\trunk and svn\trunk\a. Did you mean main? That doesn't make a lot of sense, seeing as trunk\a is just a subdirectory, then you proceed to talk about main\a. Secondly, in the second line, are you referring to the subdirectories 'a' in both main and trunk and then merging the root of trunk and main together and it not recognizing it?

Comment: 1. This is not a problem 2. You "have get rid" nothing

Comment: Read carefully about "Subtree merge" in SVN. Ask smart questions after it

Comment: @LazyBadger: I've followed your advise and read the link you posted line by line. It doesn't answer my question. If you merge a subfolder the parent's directory mergeinfo aren't updated. This is a problem..

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.stayinsync.subtree **READ IT!!!** again and again